# Unable to AutoLoad Class using Composer

Tags: autoload, composer-php

I have a project structure that looks like:

```
app/
app/models/
app/controllers/
app/views/
public/
vendor/
composer.json
```

Inside of app/controllers/IndexController.php, I have:

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

use MyApp\Models\Test;

class IndexController {

    public function __construct() {
       $t = new Test(); // can't be found
    }
}
```

Here's my composer.json:

```
{
  "require": {
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "*",
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "MyApp": "app/"
    }
  }
}
```

After updating composer.json, I run composer.phar update to update the generated autoload files.

FYI - I'm not using any type of MVC framework. This is just a custom lightweight structure I like to use for small projects.

How do I fix my project so that I can autoloaded classes from my models folder and use them properly in my controllers?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `psr-0` autoloading, then you need to follow the psr-0 spec. That means, if you specify `"MyApp": "app/"`, the class MyApp\Models\Test must be in `app/MyApp/Models/Test.php`.

Comment: Say I wanted to veer away from the psr-0 and just modify my composer.json to get it work with my existing folder structure. How would I do that?

Comment: Use `classmap` autoloading then, that supports anything. `"autoload": { "classmap": [ "app/" ] }` will scan the entire app directory for .php/.inc files and find all classes defined in any. It's less convenient for developing the package itself though because when you add a new class you should run `composer dump-autoload` again to make it discover it.