# Composer autoload full example?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I am trying to put [all](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179025/unable-to-autoload-class-using-composer) [peaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818690/using-composers-autoload?rq=1) [together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146057/composer-autoloader-psr-0-namespaces) I found about autoloading a class in composer but I can't make it work. Every example I see is missing some part. Basically it comes down to two files with 4 lines:

index.php

```
$loader = require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('Vendor\\', __DIR__.'/../app/');
new Vendor_Package_Obj();
```

app/Vendor/Package/Obj.php

```
class Obj {}
```

I also tried psr-4 and all thinkable combinations of folders and names for `Vendor Package Obj?  but no luck finding a working solution.

How can I autoload a file with composer using any of those standards?

Comment: Your class is not called `Vendor_Package_Obj`. It's called `Obj` and should be declared in a namespace.

Comment: Some examples use namespaces, other doesn't. Most example do not show Obj.php at all. Just for once give a full example. It's only a few lines...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), The fully qualified class name MUST have a top-level namespace name, also known as a "vendor namespace" and underscores have no special meaning in any portion of the fully qualified class name.

Try this:

```
cd ~
mkdir -p testproj/src/MyApp/Package
cd testproj
composer init && composer update
```

Create your index.php with this content:

```
<?php
$loader = require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('MyApp\\', __DIR__.'/src/');
$a = new MyApp\Package\Obj();
var_dump($a);
```

And put the Obj class (src/MyApp/Package/Obj.php) :

```
<?php
namespace MyApp\Package;

class Obj
{}
```

Now when you run the code:

```
php index.php
```

You should get this as output:

```
class MyApp\Package\Obj#2 (0) {
}
```

Also directory scaffolding should look like this:

```
testproj
├── composer.json
├── index.php
├── src
│   └── MyApp
│       └── Package
│           └── Obj.php
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    └── composer
        ├── ClassLoader.php
        ├── autoload_classmap.php
        ├── autoload_namespaces.php
        ├── autoload_psr4.php
        └── autoload_real.php
```

Comment: This worked after I deleted all other `Obj.php` and folders I had in `src`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @edigu can you help me with this one ? => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179503/why-am-i-getting-error-even-after-declaring-namespaces-correctly?noredirect=1#comment71522376_42179503

Comment: A very nice example to use as a template.

Comment: @edigu Does the code of `index.php` need to be put at each file which is used as page?

E.g. index.php, faq.php, about.php

Comment: If your app does not have a router or implements a kind of front controller yes. I strongly recommend having a router instead of creating separate files such as faq.php and about.php You can take a look into nikic/fastroute on GitHub for a good, framework independent example.