# PHP class not found with namespaces

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I'm new to using namespaces. In this example I made class, which handles database connection and I'm trying to use it inside the other classes. Can you explain what is wrong?

**Connection.php**

```
namespace Database;

class Connection
{
    private static $instance = null;

    private $pdo;

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;", "root", "pw");
    }

    public static function get()
    {
        if (is_null(self::$instance))
            self::$instance = new Connection();
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

**Auth.php**

```
namespace PHPAuth;

use Database\Connection;

class Auth
{
    protected $dbh;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbh = Connection::get();
        ...
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Ok, now I included autoloader and including class is now working correctly. But now I'm getting error when using `$dbh` in Auth like `$query = $this->dbh->query("SELECT * FROM...");`

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database\Connection::query()
>   in...

Comment: How are you loading/including your files? Have you set up any autoloader? Namespaces doesn't automatically load the files.

Comment: Btw, in the file with your Connection class, you need to add `use PDO;`, or that class won't be found either, since you are in the `Database` namespace. PHP's core classes are always (there might be exceptions to this?) in the top namespace.

Comment: Please include all errors you get when you run your script. Also include information about autoloader you are using (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046052/composer-autoload-full-example). What IDE do you use BTW? PhpStorm underline everything related to "class could not be found". I recomend it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks! So there was a problem with including the class. Now I set up autoloader and it's working, but I'm getting another error. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First issue with class not found

I'll add the answer (which worked for you) for the first issue for reference: *"Namespaces doesn't automatically load the files. You need to add an autoloader for that."*

#### Second issue with undefined method

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database\Connection::query()`

The answer is in the error message. You've made the class `Database\Connection` into a singleton where `Database\Connection::get()` returns an instance of itself (which doesn't have any `->query()` method), and not the actual `PDO` instance.

If you want that method to return the `PDO` instance instead, I would do something like this:

```
namespace Database;

use PDO;

class Connection
{
    private static $pdo;

    private function __construct() 
    {
        // Leave the constructor private so it still becomes
        // a singleton and so we can't instantiate this class.
    }

    public static function get()
    {
        if (is_null(self::$pdo)) {
            self::$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;", "root", "pw");
        }

        return self::$pdo;
    }
}
```

Now the `Connection` class have become a Factory for the PDO-connection.

`Connection::get()` will return the same `PDO` instance over and over and you should be able to call `$this->dbh->query("...")` from your `Auth` class.